# Why does the cursor thickness change when using tkinter text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I use a text widget in Tkinter, the cursor becomes thick if it's not column 1.

look:

[image]

but if the cursor is not in column 1, the cursor becomes thick.

[image]

See, the cursor is much thicker.
I know this can be fixed by using `insertwidth=1`, but I'm curious to know why this happens.
Is there something wrong with my system, os, or is it a problem with Tkinter?

Edit: This is also a problem in the Python IDLE. The cursor becomes thick too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the width of the cursor is two pixels by default.  When it is at column 0, only half of it (one pixel) is visible.

You can set `insertwidth=1` when creating the `Text` widget, then you can see the cursor in 1 pixel width all the time.

Comment: Wait what? The default thickness is 2? I always thought it was 1.

Comment: The default is 1 on osx, FWIW